# How to determine which package to install?

Tags: apt, apt-cache

On the Mac, since I used `node` to run NodeJS, so I assume I would do the same on Ubuntu (just like `gcc` for the GNU C Compiler).

So I typed `node`, and it says

```
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

So it seemed like it would be `node`.

But then if I use `apt-cache search ^node$` to search for its description, it showed nothing.  If I use `apt-cache search ^nodejs$`, then it would show `nodejs - evented I/O for V8 javascript`.

And so it seemed like it would be `nodejs`.

(Also, `apt-cache show node` didn't show anything, while `apt-cache show nodejs` showed a lot of info, so there seemed to be higher chance that it is `nodejs`.  However, what about the fact when I typed `node`, it said "The program 'node' can be found in the following packages: node, nodejs-legacy"?)

In this situation, how can you tell which one is the correct one?  I am less interested in knowing just which one is the correct one, but more interested to learn how to find out from the given information so far.

--
**Update:**

as per @muru's request, this is the output from

```
$ sudo apt-get update

Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates InRelease               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Sources   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Sources  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Sources        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Sources      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Sources 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main amd64 Packages         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted amd64 Packages   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Sources   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe amd64 Packages     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main amd64 Packages  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main i386 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Sources         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Sources   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Sources      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Sources    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main i386 Packages   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done

$ apt-cache show node | grep -i Desc
$                           # <-- nothing is showing up as result

$ apt-cache show node
N: Can't select versions from package 'node' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server):

To install `node` on Ubuntu, do the following:

1. Update your current packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. To add source (for more recent versions, also, node recommends to download it from here):

   ```
   wget -c https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
   ```
3. To install `node.js`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nodejs
   ```
4. You might also need `build-essential` for more features (required by npm):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Running `apt-cache show` *should* show their descriptions:

```
$ apt-cache show node | grep -i Desc
Description: Amateur Packet Radio Node program (transitional package)
Description-md5: 1278ed271672fd829c99361f93f468da
$ apt-cache show nodejs | grep -i Desc
Description: evented I/O for V8 javascript
Description-md5: e507fb472d7cdaceffc5b285a62d5c1b
```

If it doesn't, you can still visit [the Package Index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). Just go to `http://packages.ubuntu.com/<package-name>`:

- [`node`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/node)
- [`nodejs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nodejs)

As you can see, in both pages, the packages have descriptions next to their names.

Comment: interesting... my `apt-cache show node | grep -i Desc` showed nothing... and I even did a `sudo apt-get update` before this... should I do something else? I am running Ubuntu 2015-10

Comment: Do you have languages disabled for `apt`? Edit your post to include output of `apt-config dump | grep Lang`.

Comment: actually, I don't think it has anything special... it is a VM and when I installed it, I chose every either English or US English, so the output of the `apt-config dump | grep Lang` command is `Acquire::Languages "";
Acquire::Languages:: "en_US";
Acquire::Languages:: "en";
Acquire::Languages:: "none";`

Comment: @太極者無極而生 [edit] your post to include the output of `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: isn't that very long??  mine is just a VM... so my guess will be that mine is as good as anybody's

Comment: @太極者無極而生 If it's long, it's long. What difference does that make? Of course, if you don't want to solve this problem, say so and be done with it, instead of wasting my time.

Comment: ok it is done...